# Apache Spark + cassandra+Java +Spark session to display all records

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am working on a Spring Java Project and integrating Apache spark and cassandra using Datastax connector.

I have autowired sparkSession and the below lines of code seems to work.

```
Map<String, String> configMap = new HashMap<>();
    configMap.put("keyspace", "key1");
    configMap.put("table", tableName.toLowerCase());

    Dataset<Row> ds = sparkSession.sqlContext().read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(configMap)
            .load();
    ds.show();
```

But this is always giving me 20 records. I want to select all the records of table. can someone tell me how to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`show` always outputs 20 records by default, although you can pass an argument to specify how many items do you need. But `show` is usually used just for briefly examine the data, especially when working interactively.

In your case, everything is really depends on what do you want to do with the data - you already successfully loaded the data using the `load` function - after that you can just start to use normal Spark functions - `select`, `filter`, `groupBy`, etc.

P.S. You can [find here more examples](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/tree/master/spark-oss/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/spark) on using Spark Cassandra Connector (SCC) from Java, although it's more cumbersome than using Scala... And I recommend to make sure that you're using SCC 2.5.0 or higher because of the [many new features there](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all).